# Design Pattern for enterprise application

Tags: design-patterns, enterprise-architecture, enterprise-development

I read few articles about composite pattern and I want to know whether its applicable in following situation,

I found that "A Composite Entity object can represent a coarse-grained
object and all its related dependent objects"

```
public class PatientRegistrationDTO
{
    public string RegistrationNo;
    public string ID;
    public DateTime AdmitDate;    
}


public class PersonDTO
{
     public string ID{ get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

by using these two objects I need to create

```
public class Patient
  {
        public string ID{ get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public DateTime AdmitDate;
  }
```

Can I use Composite pattern for enterprise applications in here?

Is it possible for me to add some class like below?

```
public class PatientDTO
{
    public static Patient ConvertToEntity(PatientRegistrationDTO pregDTO, PersonDTO person)
    {
        Patient p = new Patient();
        p.ID= pregDTO.ID;
        p.FullName = person.FullName;
        p.AdmitDate = pregDTO.AdmitDate;

        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not? . . . .

Comment: Why yes?. . . .

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do u mean by why not?

Comment: @StephaneRolland what do u mean by why yes??

Comment: @Tilt I mean the contrary of Robert's not.

Comment: Is there some kind of collection type involved? If there's no collection (see Stephane's picture) then whatever pattern it is, it's not the Composite. If there is, you're hiding away important things from your question and so shouldn't expect a relevant answer.

Comment: @DonalFellows there's no collection involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composite pattern implies that when you call a method `perform()` on a composite (`perform()` being part of the interface contract of IComponent), the call is redirected to all its sub-components, until they are leaf elements that do an actual thing.

In your case I see absolutely no difference between the coarse and the fine grain, and which entity group/represent others as a composite.

So **I would say no**, the composite pattern really doesn't apply here.

the wikipedia class diagram may explicit my point of view: ( in this diagram perform = operation)
[image]

Comment: in enterprise design patter also does it apply same? i felt there's some difference.

Comment: First, show me a Department entity, or Service, then that would make sense.

Comment: in my scenario web service is host to enter PatientRegistrationDTO information. so when user enter those information it takes value of ID and calls the external web service. then it will return object of PersonDTO. my database class (entity class) is Patient . so i want to create Patient object using these two classes. (PatientRegistrationDTO & PersonDTO)

Comment: if i can't use composite pattern what sort of design pattern do u suggest ?

Comment: I would create a `class Patient`, who would have as `private` data members, one `PatientDTO` and one `PersonDTO`. And I would delegate the exposed public members of `class Patient` to either `PatientDTO` or to `PersonDTO`. It's not really a Design Pattern, **it's simply called Aggregation**.

Comment: @TilT but you could then almost name it an **Adapter Pattern**, if you define an `IPatient` interface that the aggregated `Patient` must implement. But it would be an adapter that adpats two classes.

Comment: thanx for your answer and also thanx for the suggestion about adapter pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your classes are allowing data to be modified by external forces via the `public` members. Since these are supposed to be Entity objects, enforce the immutability of the data. If you need to change a piece of the data, throw away the stale object and create a new one with the new data. Example:

```
public sealed class PatientRegistrationDTO
{
    private readonly string registrationNo;

    private readonly string id;

    private readonly DateTime admitDate;

    public PatientRegistrationDTO(string registrationNo, string id, DateTime admitDate)
    {
        this.registrationNo = registrationNo;
        this.id = id;
        this.admitDate = admitDate;
    }

    public string RegistrationNo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.registrationNo;
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id;
        }
    }

    public DateTime AdmitDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.admitDate;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class PersonDTO
{
     private readonly string id;

     private readonly string fullName;

     private readonly string firstName;

     public PersonDTO(string id, string fullName, string firstName)
     {
         this.id = id;
         this.fullName = fullName;
         this.firstName = firstName;
     }

     public string ID
     {
         get
         {
             return this.id;
         }
     }

     public string FullName
     {
         get
         {
             return this.fullName;
         }
     }

     public string FirstName
     {
         get
         {
             return this.firstName;
         }
     }
}
```

And, finally, I would use composition to do this:

```
public sealed class Patient
{
    private readonly PatientRegistrationDTO patientRegistration;

    private readonly PersonDTO person;

    public Patient(PatientRegistrationDTO patientRegistration, PersonDTO person)
    {
        // Appropriate nullity checks as needed here.
        this.patientRegistration = patientRegistration;
        this.person = person;
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.patientRegistration.ID;
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.person.FullName;
        }
    }

    public DateTime AdmitDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.patientRegistration.AdmitDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for yous answer. but the problem is i cant change my patient class as u suggested.